# pip install fails with ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

Tags: python, numpy, pip, windows-10, python-3.9

I'm trying to install numpy, or any other package, using pip but I received this error:

```
PS C:\Users\giuse> pip install numpy
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
```

How can I solve it?
I've installed Python 3.9.6 on Windows 10 and added Python to PATH variable. I've also tried with `--index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/`, `--trusted-host=pypi.org` and `proxy=proxy.com:8080` flags but with the same result.

Comment: Try to run under administrator. If you were under Linux, you could use sudo.

Comment: @PetrL. same error

Comment: @PetrL. In what way `sudo` helps to resolve network problems?

Comment: @phd there is a permissionerror

Comment: @PetrL. Network `ProtocolError('Connection aborted.')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python and was trying to install web3 and getting this error.
I just launched my IDE (PyCharm) as admin and it worked, thanks to [Petr L.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68951081/pip-install-fails-with-protocolerrorconnection-aborted-permissionerror13#comment121856996_68951081).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you haven't made any script called numpy.py in /simple/numpy/

Comment: This is a fresh installation of Python and pip so no script is present. /simple/numpy is the folder in which pip looks for the indexes starting from https://pypi.org

Comment: @GiuseppeTerrasi I was just checking. when you do import numpy and name your file numpy it does nonsense. Sorry, I don't have further suggestions. Maybe check you have your Python path setup correctly and reinstall Python (there may have been an error)

Comment: I'm only trying to install numpy for the moment. I've just tried to reinstall Python but nothing changed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

It seems a bug on Python 3.9.6. Downgrading to version 3.7.6 it works correctly.

Comment: Why not 3.8.6 it's newer?